# res.redirect() in express with params

Tags: node.js, express

I have a route to which I post the login information and get the user id.  I would like to pass is as a param to another route.

```
router.post('/login', function(req, res) {
      //processing
      var id = //getting id after login
      res.redirect('/page/'+ id);
});
```

The redirect is looking for a route that processes

```
router.get('/page/<id-here>'), function(req, res) {
});
```

How do I do the redirect so that I get the id as a req.param?

```
router.get('/page/:id', function(req, res) {
    var id = req.params.id;
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: [`req.param`](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#req.param) (singular) is a _function_, not an object; you probably mean [`req.params`](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#req.params) (plural).

Comment: Yes. I missed the 's'. Have edited the question.

Comment: The redirect _should_ trigger the `/page/:id` route (unless you're using [`app.param`](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.param) to only allow certain values to pass, or something).

Comment: I don't use app.param. The redirect works when I use res.redirect('/page?account='+id); The router works when I do this: router.get('/page') and get the id using req.query.account

Comment: Can you use a CLI tool or your browser's devtools to see where exactly the redirect is sending you in the `"/page/" + id` case?